# Why is the Maclaurin series for arccos centred at origin?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I imagine I have made an error somewhere, but am unable to see where I have gone wrong.

If I graph $\int_0^x\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$ I end up with a graph centred at the origin, rather than at $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ as $\cos^{-1}\left(x\right)$ should be. This approach works perfectly fine for $\sin^{-1}\left(x\right)$ when I graph $\int_0^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$ so I am confused as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Per definition Maclaurin series are **always** centered at zero.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by pre definition Maclaurin series?

Comment: A Maclaurin series are is a Taylor series at 0, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series. Is your question actually why $\arccos(0)=\tfrac{\pi}{2}?$

Comment: @gammatester: He means that the graph goes through $(0,0)$ instead of $(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\varepsilon}1\,dx = \varepsilon,$$ there is nothing strange.

Comment: I know that Maclaurin series are Taylor series at 0, but surely this doesn't mean it should be translated by pi/2? For example, the Maclaurin series of cos(x) isn't centred at the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because
$$
\int_0^x \frac{-dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \bigl[\arccos t \bigr]_0^x = \arccos x - \arccos 0
= \arccos x - \frac{\pi}{2}
.
$$
So you're not drawing the graph of $\arccos x$ but of $\arccos x - \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Oh thank you. This makes sense. So surely then the graph I want is the integral from 1 to x

Comment: Well, you rather want just $\pi/2$ plus the integral from $0$ to $x$, if you're really going to use it to obtain the Maclaurin expansion (by expanding the binomial and integrating termwise).